# USB Not Recognized

Tags: windows

Is there a way of disabling this message? According to Windows 7 my USB Keyboard doesn't work, however it does work fine. And the annoying sound of when a USB being plugged in is played every 6 seconds, along with the message saying that the device is not recognized.

I've already tried all of my USB ports, and it's probably something with the cable as it's an old keyboard, but it works fine.

Comment: Reconnecting every 6 seconds is _not_ working fine. Time for a [new KB](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/category/category_slc.asp?Recs=10&Nav=|c:533|lp:0.01:hp:24.99|&Sort=4). :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to install the correct driver, that could already solve it. 
Does your keyboard have another USB port or anything else that might cause trouble? Can you try to deactivate those in the device manager?

Comment: If you simply seek clarification from the OP you should post a comment instead.